# Variant array passed from UserForm to Module in VBA is null/empty

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a UserForm with a ListBox for the user to select values. Those values are populated in `UserForm_Initialize()` via a function call to the base module, which returns an array as variant. This works without problems.

If the user selects some values and presses a button, the buttons Click event calls another function in the base module to pass on the user-entered array and compute things. This does not work at all. The value received in the base module is always nonexistent (not even null, but I don't know the correct VBA term, nothing is there at all).

---

Things I have tried so far:

- Passing all arguments ByVal: Did not make a difference
- Using global shared variables: This did work, but I don't want to rely on them if all I do is pass a single array to a single function. This also introduces state into the code which has to be managed, especially when reusing the function
- Accessing the functions by full qualifiers: Did not make a difference. The functions are found and executed correctly, but the argument variables are empty, therefore the functions fail later on when doing the calculations.

---

My question is: *How can I pass arrays from UserForms to Modules (not vice versa) without relying on global variables and without losing the array content?*

This question may be related to [this question about passing a String from Form to Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214072/passing-variable-from-form-to-module-in-vba), but the accepted answer does not help in my case (using global variables).

Comment: Where is the code for your base module?

Comment: Show us the relevant pieces of code please.

Comment: You can see my answer (passing argument array from userform to a module with 2 methods (function or sub) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211641/passing-variant-byref-in-vba-excel-2007/35235075#35235075

Answer (score 0):

When adding the code as requested in the comments, I stumbled upon that fact that I could print the content of the array, but it would not show anything in the debugger and the size would be 0.

The size issue was because I used `Len(array)` instead of `Application.CountA(array)` and I had a leftover `On error resume next` from earlier still in the code, which meant that no error was raised and size was always set to zero... This was the reason for the strange behaviour.

Comment: `len(join(array))` would work i think. If the array is not 0 size, `ubound(array)` works too.